# AmCharts Map Disable Rollover Color on Mouseover

Tags: javascript, json, amcharts

I've checked the documentation but I cannot find it... how can I disable the rollover color on AmCharts Map on mouseover? Basically disable the change of color of map (for example, a state on US map). I don't want any mouseover interactivity or change of color. Thanks.

```
var map = AmCharts.makeChart("propertiesMap", {

"type": "map",
"listeners": [{
  "event": "mouseover",
  "method": removeListener
  }],
"dragMap": false,
"theme": "light",
"colorSteps": 5,
"mouseEnabled": false,
"selectable": false,
"zoomOnDoubleClick": false,
"dataLoader": {
    "url": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/22422.json",
    format: "json",
    "areas": [{
        "mouseEnabled": false
    }]
},

"areasSettings": {
    "autoZoom": false,
    "balloonText": "",
    "outlineThickness": 1,
    "selectable": false,
},

"valueLegend": {
    "right": 10,
    "minValue": "Cold",
    "maxValue": "Hot"
},

"zoomControl": {
    "zoomControlEnabled": false,
    "panControlEnabled": false,
    "homeButtonEnabled": false
}
});
```

Comment: Please post your JS code for the map along with your args

Comment: @AshleyBrown I've added it.

Comment: Have you tried @Pat's suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the rollover color for all states/areas, set the `rollOverColor` to `null` in your `areasSettings` object:

```
  "areasSettings": {
    // ...
    "rollOverColor": null
  },
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/34c9fc933ed0d5fedceafe508f123641?editors=0010)

Comment: Thank you so much @xorspark!

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmChart#removeListener)

`removeListener(chart, type, handler)`

So in your case:

`removeListener(myChart, 'mouseover', stateHoverFunction)`

Comment: Thank you... I've updated the code but it's not rendering for me... can you help me point out what I missed?

Comment: @Pat - This isn't correct. `removeListener` only works on the chart's custom events, not the usual browser events like `mouseover`. You also can't remove the default event such as `rollOverMapObject`

Comment: I stand corrected - you can remove *some* default events, for example [the scrollbar zoomed event](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/disabling-default-chart-scrollbar-zoom-events/). `rollOverMapObject` isn't one of them, however.